# Time based greeting app not working, swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I'm trying to make a simple time based greeting app in swift but it's not working, when I press return in the text field of my app it just freezes, Xcode brings me to `AppDelegate` and has one line with a little mark on it, I don't know whats wrong and why.

Xcode says there are no errors in my code while I'm editing it, but then the app doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func nameTextField(nameTextField: UITextField) {
        var currentTimeOfDay = ""

        let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)
        if hour >= 0 && hour < 12 {

            currentTimeOfDay = "Morning"

        } else if hour >= 12 && hour < 17 {

            currentTimeOfDay = "Afternoon"

        } else if hour >= 17 {

            currentTimeOfDay = "Evening"

        }

        nameLabel.text = "Good \(currentTimeOfDay) \(nameTextField)"       
    }  
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I am no longer in need of the answer as I was just playing around in Swift. Thank you anyway to all who answered or commented though!

-Moose

Comment: You had perhaps added a breakpoint in your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my full working app.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var helloLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!

    var heyName = "Hey"
    var greeting = ""


    func greetingLogic() {
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let currentHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date as Date)
        let hourInt = Int(currentHour.description)!

        if hourInt >= 12 && hourInt <= 16 {
            greeting = "Good Afternoon"
        }
        else if hourInt >= 7 && hourInt <= 12 {
            greeting = "Good Morning"
        }
        else if hourInt >= 16 && hourInt <= 20 {
            greeting = "Good Evening"
        }
        else if hourInt >= 20 && hourInt <= 24 {
            greeting = "Good Night"
        }
        else if hourInt >= 0 && hourInt <= 7 {
            greeting = "You should be sleeping right now"
        }

        helloLbl.text = greeting
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        greetingLogic()

    }


    @IBAction func sayHello(_ sender: UIButton) {

        helloLbl.text = greeting + ", " + nameText.text!.capitalized + "!"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just clean function

```
    private func getGreeting() -> String {
        let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

        switch hour {
        case 0..<4:
            return "Hello"
        case 4..<12:
            return "Good morning"
        case 12..<18:
            return "Good afternoon"
        case 18..<24:
            return "Good evening"
        default:
            break
        }
        return "Hello"
    }
```